# Debuging a SQL query (beginner)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, inner-join

I'm doing Google Analytics course and we're practising JOIN clauses. I'm getting an error with the following:

```
SELECT 
  name AS employee_name,
  role AS employee_role,
  departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.departments` ON
  employees.department_id = employee_data.departments.department_id
```

The error I get is: Unrecognized name: employee_data at [9:3]

I cannot see what is wrong

Comment: you need to use the complete table names or define aliases

Answer (score -1):

You are mssing aliases for the table

```
SELECT 
  employees.name AS employee_name,
  employees.role AS employee_role,
  departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.employees` As employees
INNER JOIN
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.departments`  as departments ON
  employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.employees`.name AS employee_name,
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.employees`.role AS employee_role,
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.departments`.name AS department_name
FROM 
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN
  `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.departments` 
  ON `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.employees`.department_id = `da-first-project-396518.employee_data.departments`.department_id
```

Comment: you should really use aliases like in my answer, it is much more comprehensive

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).